# SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host

Tags: docker

I'm getting a security warning below after building a docker image why am I getting this warning? I tried on a Linux server and I don't get this security warning.

```sh
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this issue by [thaJeztah](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/20397#issuecomment-185471832) on Github

> That warning was added, because the Windows filesystem does not have an option to mark a file as 'executable'. Building a linux image from a Windows machine would therefore break the image if a file has to be marked executable.
> For that reason, files are marked executable by default when building from a windows client; the warning is there so that you are notified of that, and (if needed), modify the Dockerfile to change/remove the executable bit afterwards.